# CodeIgniter strong password policy with compulsory uppercase/lowercase letters and digits

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, passwords

I want to require the user to choose a strong password with at least one uppercase letter and one digit. How do I enforce this policy when validating a form with  CodeIgniter?

Comment: Using callback and some regular expressions https://stackoverflow.com/a/65401563/7186739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the default `Form_validation` class and create a custom validation rule for your custom password validation.

To extend the default class you need to create a `MY_Form_validation` class and put it into your `application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`. Here's an example:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Extension of CI's default form validation library.
 *
 * @see system/libraries/Form_validation.php
 */
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    /**
     * Custom password validation rule.
     *
     * @param  string $pass Password to check.
     *
     * @return bool       
     */
    public function check_pass($pass)
    {
        // It's a good practice to make sure each validation rule does
        // its own job. So we decide that this callback does not check
        // for the password field being required. If we need so, we just
        // prepend the "required" rule. For example: "required|min_length[8]|check_pass"
        //
        // So we just let it go if the value is empty:
        if (empty($pass))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        // This sets the error message for your custom validation
        // rule. %s will be replaced with the field name if needed.
        $this->set_message('check_pass', 'Password needs to have at least one uppercase letter and a number.');

        // The regex looks ahead for at least one lowercase letter,
        // one uppercase letter and a number. IT'S NOT TESTED THOUGH.
        return (bool) preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$/', $pass);
    }

}
```

With this custom class in place, the `check_pass` validation rule will be available to your controllers when setting rules.

If you're too lazy to add this custom class or you already have the validation function implemented somewhere else, you might want to use custom validation callbacks by prepending `callback_` to the name of existing functions and use them as validation rules. See [validation callbacks](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) for more on this.

I don't recommend the latter approach though as it messes up with where validation rules reside. There are some cases that we MUST use custom callbacks that not reside in the validation class, outside those cases (which is not yours) all rules better be in your custom class.

P.S. Also consider this:

[image: Password Strength]

Comment: **Severity: Warning
Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 31
Filename: libraries/MY_Form_validation.php
Line Number: 130**
I get this error when i hit the register button and when i use callback_check_pass in the model where the validation rules are set the registration is still succesful

Comment: I updated the regex a few minutes ago. It works now. Just strip the extra parenthese at the end.

Comment: When you put the rule in your custom  `MY_Form_validation` class you don't need the extra `callback_` prepended. It's just `check_pass`.

Comment: it is still logging in succesfully with simple lowercase text, the message should contain 1 uppercase letter and 1 digit isn't displaying
Below is the code i am using in my model:
`'password' => array(
   'field' => 'password', 
   'label' => 'Password', 
   'rules' => 'trim|min_length[6]|matches[password_confirm]|check_pass'
  ),
  'password_confirm' => array(
   'field' => 'password_confirm', 
   'label' => 'Confirm password', 
   'rules' => 'trim|min_length[6]|matches[password]|check_pass'
  ),`

Comment: First; I had a typo, `preg_match` does not return booleans and it can mess with your passwords, we need to typecast its return value. (I updated the code) Second; to test, change the `check_pass` rule to always return `FALSE` and see if it gets called. If it does, you should work on the regex then.

Comment: I've just tested the code, it works fine after the typecast thing.

Comment: You Sir are amazing, I am so grateful for your help :)